# Randomize Saved movieclips stored on children

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having a hard time with some code in actionscript 3.0. I don'y know how to randomize the movieclips stored on child and pick only 8 movieclips wherein there are 10 movieclips stored. I hope you'll be able to help me with this problem. thanks

Here is the code:

```
    //start stage function
    this.mainmc.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, setupStage1);
    this.waitingCounter=0;

//set up current stage
function setupStage1 (e:Event) {
    //wait for timeline
    if (this.waitingCounter<2) {
        this.waitingCounter++;
        //not ready yet, do nothing
        return;
    }
    //Start the timer
    timer.start();
    //hide hint
    this.mainmc.hintmc.visible=false;
    //hide star animation
    this.mainmc.starAnimation.visible=false;
    //listener for hint button
    this.mainmc.hintbut.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showHint1);
    //create objects array
    this.obArr=[];
    //count the objects on stage
    for (var n=0; n<this.mainmc.numChildren; n++) {
        //get the children
        var ob=this.mainmc.getChildAt(n);
        //only take movie clips
        if (ob is MovieClip) {
            //only count the movie clips that have name declared
            if (ob.myname!=null) {
                //push to array
                this.obArr.push (MovieClip(ob));
            }
        }
    }
```

on the code above, the code will store all the movieclips that are present in the stage. it stores them in a child. each 10 movieclips has a variable name "myname".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You're going to need to provide more information about exactly what you're having an issue with. You can't just post a big chunk of code along with your required functionality and say "here, do my work for me!" This isn't the way the site works. Let us know exactly where you're having an issue, with what code and people will be more than happy to help.

Comment: i'm so sorry. its my first time to do this. ok i'll edit my post ^_^ thanks

Comment: is my question good or confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to randomly sort items within an array, use the array.sort method and within your sort function, simply create a random number between 1 and 2. If it's 1, return true, if it's 2, return false. Here is an actionscript 2 snippet along with a link to a couple of tutorials:

```
var a:Array = new Array(“a”, “b”, “c”, “d”, “e”);
function shuffle(a,b):Number {
var num : Number = Math.round(Math.random()*2)-1;
return num;
}
var b:Array = a.sort(shuffle);
trace(b);
```

http://mrsteel.wordpress.com/2007/05/26/random-array-in-as2-as3-example-using-sort/

http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/75-random-sort-function-comes-handy-when-building-applications-with-playlists.html

This is a much longer and more in-depth tutorial:
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-randomly-shuffle-an-array-in-as3/